# Obfuscate a Bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to obfuscate my Bash script, so that it's still executable but if you try to read it you won't understand it. And my question is, how can you achieve this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Possible to mangle Bash scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88399/possible-to-mangle-bash-scripts)