# Shell (.sh) Compiler

Tags: command-line, compiler, sh

How can I compile a shell(.sh) file?
(S.H.C 3.8.9), I am working only on the same server and not on other servers.

Comment: `.sh` files are normally shell *scripts*, which do not get compiled but get interpreted by the shell (e.g. Bash) directly. And  what is that "(S.H.C 3.8.9) supposed to mean?

Comment: https://github.com/existz/shc-3.8.9

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I see no reason to use that software you linked.

Comment: Whats specific issue or problem are you having with `shc`? if you want a simple usage example, there's one in this recent answer: [Obfuscate a Bash script](https://askubuntu.com/a/920041/178692)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

With `shc` you can compile a shell script into executable file like so:

```
$ cat myscript.sh                                          
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello World

stat /etc/passwd
$ shc -vf myscript.sh                                      
shc shll=bash
shc [-i]=-c
shc [-x]=exec '%s' "$@"
shc [-l]=
shc opts=
shc: cc  myscript.sh.x.c -o myscript.sh.x
shc: strip myscript.sh.x
shc: chmod go-r myscript.sh.x
$ ./myscript.sh.x
Hello World
  File: '/etc/passwd'
  Size: 2905        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 6041065     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-03-17 15:41:35.682814004 -0600
Modify: 2017-03-17 15:41:35.686813953 -0600
Change: 2017-03-17 15:41:35.694813853 -0600
```

There are of course other compilers, for instance [ccsh](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/faqs/ccshlit.html). Generally it is not necessary to compile scripts unless you want to obfuscate it for copyright reasons.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6423007/3701431) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling is for turning source code into an executable file.  An example would be compiling a program written in C.

Perl, bash, korn, cshell and other scripting languages do not need to be compiled and, in fact, compilers for these tools are not needed and do not exist.

Comment: `in fact, compilers for these tools are not needed and do not exist` This is not exactly true. While direct compilers don't exist,  there are programs that generate C code or something similar, and compile that.  So you could say there are indirect-compilers.

Comment: True enough.  I've "compiled" scripts on occasion because I wanted to hide the source from prying eyes.  Mostly when running something involving root access.  From the wording of the OP's question, I got the impression that obfuscation was not the objective.